# Node.js how to make multiple http requests using request.js

Tags: node.js, http, concurrency, request

I'm programming kind of web-scrape-client with Node.js and request.js, async npm modules.

I was expecting request() calls in async.times() function for each urls will make concurrent requests to the server.

but the actual request fires one by one even though as many times as urls request() function called within async.times().

code like below

```
request.defaults({
pool:{
    maxSockets:50
} });
...
...
async.times(scrapeTarget.totalPage, function(index, next) {
                    scrapeTarget.downloadedListPages++;
                    var reqPageNum = index+1;

                    var listReqOpt = requestUtil.makeOption('url:listPage', requestOption);
                    listReqOpt.url += '?page=' + reqPageNum;
                    listReqOpt.jar = cookieJar;

                    console.log('['+reqPageNum+'] : request page');

                    console.time(index);

                    request(listReqOpt, function(err, response, body) {
                            // response job here !
                                console.log('['+reqPageNum+'] : got response');
                                console.timeEnd(index);

                        next(null,{'done':reqPageNum});
                    }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(archiveDir + '/listPage' + reqPageNum + '.html'));

                }, 
 ...
 ...);
```

**and it's RESULT**

```
[1] : request page
[2] : request page
[3] : request page
[4] : request page
[5] : request page
[6] : request page
[7] : request page
...
[212] : request page
[213] : request page
[214] : request page
[5] : got response
4: 3607ms
[3] : got response
2: 5844ms
[4] : got response
3: 8171ms
[1] : got response
0: 10221ms
[2] : got response
1: 12689ms
[6] : got response
5: 14313ms
[7] : got response
6: 16630ms
[8] : got response
...
[16] : got response
15: 36488ms
[17] : got response
16: 38807ms
[18] : got response
17: 41000ms
[19] : got response
18: 43193ms
...
...
I break running because it takes too long.
```

I'm running the code with
Node.js 0.10.x
request 2.36.0
on Ubuntu 14.04 and Cloud 9 bash

How can I make request run in parallel simultaneously?

Comment: Try use timesSeries(http://goo.gl/6jviF7) instead of times.

Comment: @Alexander wondering the reason behind your comment since timesSeries notes that: "The next iterator is only called once the current one has completed." that is exactly the opposite of parallel/simultaneous connection.

Comment: @goodjoon Any chance your target URL is assuming your are trying to DoS and rate limiting you? How are the response time for 1 or 5 requests, instead of 200?